# PHP Json decode is ok, but decoded values are void

Tags: php, json, post, decode, void

I used this code to decode json, sent with curl (POST):

```
$json_obj = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input')); // JSON as obj
var_dump($json_obj);
$id_a = $json_obj -> {'$id_a'}; 
$id_b =  $json_obj -> {'$id_b'};
$value = $json_obj -> {'$value'};
```

It should works fine, because var_dump() says:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
  ["id_a"]=>
  int(1)
  ["id_b"]=>
  int(1)
  ["value"]=>
  float(89.35)
}
```

Then I use these vars to make a sql query:

```
$sqlcmd = "INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (ID_A, ID_B, VALUE) 
          VALUES  (".$id_a.", ".$id_b.", ".$value.")";
```

I pass it to mysql_query(), but here it is how it reads $sqlcmd:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (ID_A, ID_B, VALUE)
VALUES  (, , )
```

Void values...

Any hint? Where I am mistaking? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You aren't setting the variables correctly.

```
$id_a = $json_obj->id_a; 
$id_b =  $json_obj->id_b;
$value = $json_obj->value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have extra $ signs in your code such as:

```
$id_a = $json_obj -> {'$id_a'};
```

Try this instead:

```
$id_a = $json_obj -> {'id_a'}; 
$id_b =  $json_obj -> {'id_b'};
$value = $json_obj -> {'value'};
```